# Reference for image drawn by yourself, but originated from others?

Tags: citations, graphics

I am using some images (among others: Laser niveaus) in my thesis. I am drawing them myself with tikz, but as a guidance I use images and data from papers and books. Should I reference them, and if yes, how?

Comment: In particular, [this answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/56631/11365) to the linked duplicate addresses your question exactly, as far as I can tell.